# What is the "j" expression for the "maximum consecutive ones" problem?

Tags: j, apl

In the paper "[Combinatory Logic and Combinators in Array Languages](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codereport/Content/main/Publications/Combinatory_Logic_and_Combinators_in_Array_Languages.pdf)" they give a solution in APL:

```
      vec ← 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
      ⍝ split (partition) on zeroes
      ⊆⍨vec
┌───┬─────┬─┐
│1 1│1 1 1│1│
└───┴─────┴─┘
      ⍝ size of each sublist
      ≢ ̈⊆⍨vec
2 3 1
      ⍝ max reduction
      ⌈/≢¨⊆⍨vec
3
```

For clarity, they also note:

> The final maximum consecutive ones APL solution can be translated for those who don’t read APL:
> `reduce(max, map(length, W(partition, vec)))`

So, how would one express the following in J?

```
 ⌈/≢¨⊆⍨vec
```

The `⊆` symbol seems to be a "partition" operator.  It's not clear this exists in J but I may have just missed it.  Curious what the above expression would be in "J".

Comment: Short answer is the “cut” conjunction `;.`; for example, `>./  #;._1  ]0, 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1  NB. Returns 3`. I’ll try to find the time for a formal answer later. If I can’t or don’t, anyone at all is free to use this comment as a basis of their answer. No need for attribution.

Comment: Btw, `(⌈/¯1-2-/∘⍸1,1,⍨~)` is a much more efficient function for computing this.

Answer (score 4):

Dan Bron's answer in the comments is the way to go for sure. I did a video on this problem and if you are interested you can watch me walk through the different options. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbi_PMVbeaQ  The version I ended preferring was

`t=:[: >./ [: #;. _2 ,&0`

but I also look at

`t=:[: {: [: $ [: ];. _2 ,&0`

as an alternative.

Comment: Abusing `];.` for its result shape is delicious. Love it.

Comment: thanks for the link to the video.  more than i could have hoped for

Answer (score 3):

To provide a different point of view, the maximum number of `1`s in a row is also the maximum of the difference between consecutive indices of `0`s in the array (minus one), for which J (almost) has a primitive: `I.` (up to a `-.`). So the following works too:

```
t=: [: -&1 [: >./ [: 2&(-~/;._3) [: I. -.
```